# Сделать секцию symtab загружаемой

Tags: компоновщик, ld

я делаю свое ядро и пытаюсь сделать секцию symtab, а так же strtab загружаемыми, но они не добавляются в сегменты.
Objdump показывает:

```
build/kernel.elf:       file format ELF32-i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      Address          Type
  0               00000000 0000000000000000
  1 .text         00001610 0000000000100000 TEXT
  2 .data         000009f0 0000000000101610 TEXT BSS
  3 .eh_frame     000003b8 0000000000102000 DATA
  4 .rodata       000004ac 00000000001023c0 DATA
  5 .symtab       00000740 0000000000000000
  6 .strtab       00001324 0000000000000000
  7 .shstrtab     00000047 0000000000000000
  8 .comment      00000012 0000000000000000
  9 .bss          00002000 0000000000000014 BSS
```

То-есть нужные сегменты не загружаются. Что надо прописать в скрипте линковки, чтобы эти секции загружались?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SECTIONS { 
       .text : { *(.text) *(.symtab) *(strtab)}
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]